# piecewise function

Tags: math-mode

So this is a piecewise defined function I have that I need to talk about:

```
   f(a,b) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       \text{open} & : \text{RMSD}_\text{s-open}\ge6, \text{RMSD}_\text{closed}\ge6\\
       \text{closed} & : \text{RMSD}_\text{closed}\le2 \\
       \text{semiopen} & : \text{RMSD}_\text{s-open}\le2\\
       \text{transition} & :f(a,b)\notin\{\text{open}, \text{closed}, \text{semiopen}\} \\

     \end{array}
   \right.
```

So what's the way to align up the colons (conditions) so that it looks all nice and pretty?

Also, if I want to describe transition to be the value of the function when none of the conditions of the previous 3 are satisfied, is the way I wrote it out with `f(a,b)` not belonging to the set `{open,closed,semiopen}` a good way of writing it? seems really unprofessional...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).  Just changing the `lr` to a `l@{}l`, should give you what you desire.   The `@{}` removes the inter-column spacing. However, you should consider the `cases` environment.

Answer (score 68):

You can use the `cases` environment from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[   
f(a,b) = 
     \begin{cases}
       \text{open,} &\quad\text{if RMSD}_\text{s-open}\ge6, \text{RMSD}_\text{closed}\ge6\\
       \text{closed,} &\quad\text{if RMSD}_\text{closed}\le2 \\
       \text{semiopen,} &\quad\text{if RMSD}_\text{s-open}\le2\\
       \text{transition,} &\quad\text{otherwise.} \\ 
     \end{cases}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Regarding the other issue, it is usual to write "otherwise".

Answer (score 11):

If instead of use `lr` for the column alignment you use `l@{}l`, you get the desired result:

[image]

### Notes:

- The `@{}` removes the inter column spacing.
- As per barbara beeton's suggestion I added a `\thinspace` before the colon by a adding a `@{\thinspace}` between the two columns.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
  f(a,b) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{@{}l@{\thinspace}l}
       \text{open}  &: \text{RMSD}_\text{s-open}\ge6, \text{RMSD}_\text{closed}\ge6\\
       \text{closed} &: \text{RMSD}_\text{closed}\le2 \\
       \text{semiopen} &: \text{RMSD}_\text{s-open}\le2\\
       \text{transition} &: f(a,b)\notin\{\text{open}, \text{closed}, \text{semiopen}\} \\

     \end{array}
   \right.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: i think this would look better with a thin space between "transition" and the colon.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Good point. Have incorporated your suggestion.